# PHP MYSQL -> Display dates saved as 'date' type from MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm still getting used to using PHP and MYSQL so please bear with me.

I have a database table called 'employee_datetable' that with a field called "datetime" contains 365 records of actual dates for the next year (August 13, 2014 to August 13, 2015).

I want to write a MYSQL query that retrieves 7 dates and displays them in a row while in readable format such as "Sept 24, 2014".

Right now the dates are stored as date types and displayed as "2014-09-24" etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**PHP Code**:

```
$dates_sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) FROM employee_datetable LIMIT 7"; 
$PhpDate = strtotime($dates_sql);
$FormattedPhpDate = date('M d, Y', $PhpDate );

echo "Selected Dates from the query: " . $FormattedPhpDate;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use something like [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**pdo**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to execute your query and extract the data. Here's the general idea, using `mysqli`:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$dates_sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) AS tstamp FROM employee_datetable LIMIT 7";
$result = $mysqli->query($dates_sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $FormattedPhpDate = date('M d, Y', $row['tstamp']);
    echo "Date: " . $FormattedPhpDate . "<br/>";
}
```

*Note: Since you are using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` in your query there is no need to convert the date to a timestamp using `strtotime()`*

---

*For more info see documentation for [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), specifically [**mysqli_query**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [**mysqli_fetch_array**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)*

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M %w, %Y');
-> 'August 5, 2014'
```

Or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%b %w, %Y');
-> 'Aug 5, 2014'
```

Of course, you may use your `datetime` column instead of using `NOW()`