# PHP MYSQL: Match Date in MYSQL Query to PHP variable that holds a date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to match a date from my database to a PHP variable that contains date data that was converted to a string.  However my query is not returning any results.

The database field that contains the date data is 'datetime'.

PHP Code:

```
$todays_date = strtotime("today");
$converted_todays_date = date("m/d/Y", $todays_date);

$dates_sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) AS tstamp FROM employee_datetable WHERE STR_TO_DATE(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y') = '$converted_todays_date'";
$result = $usermysqli->query($dates_sql);

// Additional Code that I forgot to add before

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $FormattedPhpDate = date('M d, Y', $row['tstamp']);

      echo "<th><div id=day" . $FormattedPhpDate . "</div></th>";

    }
```

Right now there is no date being outputted.  I actually put in the wrong part of the code before.

Comment: You asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/25320561/ and received an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25320648/ that you accepted; what's changed since?

Comment: You have a missing `>` in `echo "<th><div id=day" . $FormattedPhpDate . "</div></th>";`

Comment: @Fred-ii that's just a typo that I made when I copied the code over.

Comment: See the answers below then and fix the typo in your code/question.

Comment: is that still a typo? dive doesn't have >

Comment: I actually found an easier approach to my problem by using MySQL's CURDATE() function instead of matching 2 dates.  Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `DateTime` Field you can simply send date in query as `date(Y-m-d H:i:s);`  from PHP to match it exactly. If you only want to compare only date part then use `Date()` mySql function to perform the comparison.